# hyperref/bookmark package: suppress/override a single bookmark

Tags: hyperref, bookmarks

So I am using `hyperref` to generate pdf bookmarks but one of my section names uses greek letters, which disappears in the pdf bookmark. So I want to override that bookmark (and only that bookmark).

MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[bookmarksnumbered]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{Theorem of $\alpha$ something}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I want the section title to still appear as greek letter in the toc and body, but redefine the bookmark to `Theorem of alpha something`. Using

```
\currentpdfbookmark{\thesection\ Theorem of alpha something}{}
```

simply creates another bookmark, not replace the existing one

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Greek letters can also be used in bookmarks:

- Unicode encoding is needed, because the 8-bit PDFDocEncoding does not contain all letter and symbols. This can be achieved by option `unicode` or `pdfencoding=auto`.
- Option `psdextra` redefines lots of math symbol commands to work within bookmarks.

Example:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[
  bookmarksnumbered,
  pdfencoding=auto,
  psdextra,
]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{Theorem of $\alpha$ something}
\end{document}
```

An alternative is the use of `\texorpdfstring`. The first argument is the normal text, the second the replacement for the bookmarks:

```
\section{Theorem of \texorpdfstring{$\alpha$}{\textalpha}}
```

This gets also rid of the warnings about the dollars, which enable and disable math mode – bookmarks do not know about TeX's math mode.

Comment: Thanks, that is quick. And I totally dodged the XY problem.